# Why does 'Disks' Utility mounting does not work?

Tags: gnome, mount

Ubuntu, for some reason does not allow mounting drives through the 'Disks' utility. I went to **More Actions -> Edit Mount Options -> Mount At Startup** and pushed the check button, restarted the computer, and got a start up screen error message stating that there was an error mounting the drive "Press 'S' to skip", etc. I tried changing the options but it didn't work and I had to disable the automatic mount options.

Comment: Let me guess: The partitions you're trying to mount belong to another OS?

Comment: No, but it is an FAT32 partition.

Comment: I also have this problem, on my two computers. mounting the disks through fstab works fine though